# Apache server (on windows) - can't connect when not connecting through lan

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, connection, timeout

Well this is strange - but I can't connect to the my apache server when I'm at another (global) IP address.

I'm connecting at port 9000, and when doing it in the browser (even though I type in my external IP) it works.

However when I connect from another place it simply "times out" it seems? My apache config:

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#

ServerRoot "xyz"

Listen 9000

LoadModule wsgi_module  modules/mod_wsgi-py34-VC10.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin example@example.com

DocumentRoot "xyz/htdocs"
<Directory "xyz/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>


<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "xyz/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Now testing a random port at [canyouseeme](http://canyouseeme.org/) returns "connection refused" (as expected). However the port 9000 simply "times out". No log on apache is shown that I ever am trying to connect on it though. - Same for my mobile phone, if I connect through it using WIFI/same LAN I get an inernet page shown correctly.

However if I connect through the mobile network it times out.

Now I did enable port-forwarding in my router. And for the sake of testing, I also removed my router and connected directly to my ISP. - The same problem occurs.

I've disabled windows firewall completely during testing to see if it's a problem - but it doesn't fix anything. Oh and just for completeness, the index.html:

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Comment: It sounds like your ISP might be doing NAT, therefore preventing you from receiving external connections.  What is your WAN IP on your router (or at least the first 2 octets)?

Comment: @heavyd 2.139.125.* is my WAN IP (with the star changing each time I reconnect).